# Stability of zero

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Determine stability of zero in \begin{cases} x'=y \\ y'=-f(x) \end{cases}

Here $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is class $\mathcal{C}^1, f(0)=0$ and $xf(x)>0$ for $x \neq 0$.

Could you help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Find a Lyapunov function $V$ of the form
$$
V(x,y)=F(x)+y^2,
$$
for some suitable nonnegative function $F$.

Comment: Well, the whole problem is that I'm not experienced when it comes to looking for Lapunov functions...

Comment: Which is why I pointed you in the direction of one. Did you find $F$?

Comment: Thank you, but shouldn't $V$ go from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$? I know I should check that $V^{-1}(0)=(0,0), $ and that $<\text{grad} V(x,y), g(x,y)> \le 0$ for $(x,y) \neq 0$. Here $g(x.y) = (y, -f(x))$

Comment: So... did you find some $F$ such that $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}V(x(t),y(t))=0$ for every $t$?

Comment: Oh, I did. It is $V(x,y)=-x^2+y^2$ and $0$ is unstable.

Comment: No, $V(x,y)=-x^2+y^2$ is NOT invariant by the dynamics (and these considerations do not show that $(0,0)$ is unstable).

Comment: Ok, you are right. $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}V(x(t),y(t))=(F(x(t))+y(t)^2)'=F'(x(t)x'(t)+2y(y)y'(t)=x'(t)(F'(x(t))-f(x))$. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. So... which function $F$ interests you?

Comment: $F(x)= \int f(x)dx$?

Comment: Please write down things explicitely and correctly. Here $F(x)=\int f(x)dx$ is meaningless (how is the RHS a function of $x$?).

Comment: Isn't antiderivative of a function of $x$ a function of $x$?

Comment: It all depends what you consider precisely. What is $F(3)$ for instance?

Comment: I think I see the problem. What should $F$ look like, then?

Comment: You showed that $F$ ought to be such that $F'(x)=f(x)$ for every $x$. So... what $F$ could be?

Comment: Could $F$ be equal $-y$?

Comment: No. What is F(3)?

Comment: $F(x)=C+ \int_1^x f(s)ds$, so $F(3)=C+ \int_1^3 f(s)ds$?

Comment: Make it $F(x)=\int_0^xf(s)ds$ and we can (finally!) close this exchange. Good job. (Here is a suggestion; next time, start to *think* before the 15th comment...)

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your patience.